# How to update value of a "usercert" property in LDAP AD

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryentry, directorysearcher

I have a requirement where I need to update the value saved in the property ("usercert") of a computer present in active directory.

// Retrieving properties value from AD

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAPPath, LDAPUser, DecryptPwd(LDAPPwd, LDAPKey)); 
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry); 
searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=computer)(Name=" + MachineName + "))"); 
result = searcher.FindOne(); 
byte[] text= (byte[])result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["usercert"].Value;
```

// Updateing new value to AD string updatedText= "New Text";

```
if (result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["usercert"] != null && 
              result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["usercert"].Value != null) 
{
     byte[] updatedTextByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(updatedText);
     result.GetDirectoryEntry().InvokeSet("usercert", updatedPassByte);
     //(result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["usercert"]).Value = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(updatedText);
     //result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["usercert"].Add(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(updatedText));
     //result.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["usercert"][0] = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(updatedText);
     result.GetDirectoryEntry().CommitChanges();  
}
```

I tried with all of the above commented code but nothing works for me. Can you please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling [GetDirectoryEntry()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult.getdirectoryentry) creates a new `DirectoryEntry` object each time you call it, which you can see in the source code [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.DirectoryServices/System/DirectoryServices/SearchResult.cs,28).

So when you do this:

```
result.GetDirectoryEntry().CommitChanges();
```

It's creating a brand new `DirectoryEntry` object and calling `CommitChanges()` on that. So nothing is changed.

You will need to call `GetDirectoryEntry()` only once and make changes to that object. For example:

```cs
var resultDe = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
resultDe.Properties["usercert"]).Value = whatever;
resuleDe.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: I already tried by calling result.GetDirectoryEntry() once and using that object to update and commit but CommitChanges() throws "Access is denied." exception.

Comment: That means the account you're running this with (`LDAPUser`) doesn't have permission to update that account (or maybe just that attribute on that account).

Comment: Thanks Grabriel! I asked the concerned team to check for the necessary permission.